# What does "Attempt to change the value of the constant" mean in SAS?

Tags: sas

```
data _null_;
    call missing('VAR1', 'VAR2');
run;
```

results in:

```
ERROR 135-185: Attempt to change the value of the constant 'VAR1' in the MISSING subroutine call.
```

What's going on? Answering my own question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
data _null_;
    call missing(VAR1, VAR2);
run;
```

The MISSING call routine takes variable names as parameters, not character constants *containing* variable names. Doh!

Answering my own question in order to import this error message into the internet, as I couldn't find any reference to it previously.

Comment: This received an overwhelming view count obs=36 over the past 8 months. On the other hand, I just noticed that you allowed a full 4 minutes before answering the question yourself. Oh, I understand now! You might want to consider asking SAS questions on the statistics SE, it isn't called that, some other name instead. Unless they are all R folks over there. (I mention that because I saw your new question too).